# Passing a null to a callee that requires a non_null argument after switch to Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios9

I'm fairly new to Obj-C, but I'm trying to build some code on Xcode 7 that previously worked in Xcode 6.
Specifically, I'm having trouble with this:

```
[_webView loadData:[_text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
          MIMEType:@"application/xml"
  textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
           baseURL:nil];
```

I keep getting an error saying:

> Passing a null to a callee that requires a non_null argument after
>   switch to xcode 7.

I understand that this is because of the baseURL but I don't know what an alternative I can pass is that has the same effect. Thanks.

Comment: The baseURL is used to ensure that short links in the document can be expanded - presumably your document/data doesn't have any of these so you can just pass an empty string `@""` to satisfy the non-null requirement

Comment: @Paulw11 `baseURL:` takes an `NSURL`, not `NSString`.

Comment: Ahh. Good point. Still - the concept is the same, some url that can be ignored anyway

Answer (score 7):

```
[... baseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"] ];
```

taken from 
http://iaintheindie.com/2015/08/16/updating-apps-for-ios-9/

regards

Comment: This works and should be marked as the correct answer. I use MIMEType:@"application/pdf", but it seems to be working fine.